# command line tool for export data from server to server

Tags: sql-server, command-line, batch-file

In SqlServer Management Studio, if we click on data database there is menu task > export data.
This help me to export this database to another server.

However, I need to run this wizard to complete this task and need to specify source and destination sever information every time that I want to use it.

I think it would be convenient if I could use command line to do the same task and write batch file to automate it.

Please could you help me give some suggestion or introduce me a command line program that can do this task since I googled  search but not found any useful information.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can use [BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) Utility

```
BCP Out 
BCP server.schema.TableName out c:\TableName.txt -c -t -T –SServerName -UUsername -Password

BCP In 
BCP server.schema.TableName In c:\TableName.txt -c -t -T –SServerName -UUsername -Password
```

The 1st statement is to `export` the data to a csv file and `BCP IN` is used to import the data from csv file to `Destination` table

Here 
`-T` stands for Trusted connection and `-t` represents field delimeter

You can write these BCP commands in batch file

Or you can create a simple `ssis` package for exporting the data

Comment: Thank you so much for fast reply, it works.